# Invalid use of non-static member function in constructor

Tags: c++

I have this class:

```
class Displayer
{
public:
  enum FlagDisplay { NOT_DISPLAY, DISPLAY };

  Displayer() {}
  ~Displayer() {}

  Displayer::FlagDisplay bar1() const { return DISPLAY; }
  Displayer::FlagDisplay bar2() const { return NOT_DISPLAY; }

  void displayImg(const cv::Mat& image, const std::string& name, FlagDisplay flg)
  {
    if (flg == DISPLAY)
    {
      cv::imshow(name, image);
      cv::waitKey();
    }
  }

  void closeAllWindows() { cv::destroyAllWindows(); }
};
```

And I have another class that has a member of type `Displayer`. When I try to initialize it in the constructor I get an `error: invalid use of non-static member function`. I do not see any call of functions in the *static manner* (`Displayer::`). Because the code is very big, what else shall I search for to find the problem?

---

The constructor of the class is this:

```
RunSolution::RunSolution(const cv::BOWImgDescriptorExtractor& bowDEIn, const ConfigFile& configFileIn,
                         const Auth& authIn, const ClassifierPtr& classifierIn, const Displayer& displayerIn)
  : m_bowDE(bowDEIn),
    m_configFile(configFileIn),
    m_io(m_configFile.getOutputFolder),
    m_s3Service(authIn),
    m_classifier(classifierIn),
    m_detector(cv::FeatureDetector::create(m_configFile.getClassifierDetectorType())),
    m_display(displayerIn) {}
//     error here       ^^
```

Comment: Is the error coming from the other class's constructor? If so, we need to see that.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I have tested something similar, but couldn't get the same error, I'll edit soon

Comment: I've added a similar class, I have tested it but I cannot get the same error, so what shall I search for?

Comment: You need to show us some code that actually exhibits the error. We can't help without that.

Comment: Error messages have line numbers in them. Why not look at the line in question?

Comment: I have posted the code where it is used... the lines are the copy constructor in the constructor of RunSolution, I mark it

Comment: lines like this `m_configFile.getOutputFolder` make it look like you are forgetting to actually call the functions.

Comment: I have corrected the missing parenthesis and the error is still there

Comment: Does the error indeed go away if you remove the last `m_display(displayerIn)`? Or does perhaps the error message refer to the initialization-list as a whole? I like @Skizz' hunch.

Comment: Remember, you should not (cannot?) use members before they have been initialized which happens in *class declaration order*, not in the init order in the ctor init list. So if `m_configFile` is *declared* (in the class) after `m_io`, you cannot use it in `m_io`'s initialization.

Comment: I would also like to see `RunSolution`'s class definition and the corrected init list code (where functions are called instead of being "mentioned").

Comment: Sorry, I had two forgotten `()`: `m_configFile.getOutputFolder` and `m_configFile.getClassifierDetectorType`. Adding them has fixed my problem... I have not seen the both of them...